# The size of log files is still big after logrotate on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, log, logrotate

`logrotate` was setup on Ubuntu 20.04 to limit the besu log file size to 10MB, keep 4 weeks log with rotating weekly and delete the old log file. Here is the besu conf:

```
#for besu log
/home/log/besu/* {
        size 10M
        missingok
        rotate 4
        weekly
        postrotate
                /usr/bin/find /home/log/besu/ -name "node*.log.*" -type f -mtime +0 -exec rm {}
\;
        endscript
}
```

The log file is named as `node[1-4].log`. Here is the `ls` output:

[image]

As the output shows, there are 18 files started with `node1` and the file size is 1.6GB. It seems that none of the above conf goal has been achieved.  What is missing in the log conf file?

Comment: Silly question, but you’ve confirmed the process that runs the script has access to the log location, yes? Are the logs actually being written to `/home/log` and not `/var/log`? 

Comment: The log is written to /home/log by code and the owner of the log file under /home/log is root which is the user I have log in.